# How to make "%n" equal to "\n"

Tags: java, string

Why isn't `b` equal to `true` if you run this code on Windows?

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
String s=String.format("%n");
boolean b="\n".equals(s);
```

I want `s` to be `"\n"` and not `"\r\n"`, even on Windows.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Because my code should produce the same result on all platforms.

Comment: you should just use `\n` instead of `%n` ... unless the code is not under your control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way here is reflection:

```
Field lineSeparator = System.class.getDeclaredField("lineSeparator");

lineSeparator.setAccessible(true);
lineSeparator.set(null, "\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, `lineSeparator` is defined and initialized in `System` class.

Before you call `System.setPropety()`, the `System` class is already initalized, and the `lineSeparator` is initialized to the system property at that moment. It won't be changed later.

You'll have to pass the system property on command line option...

Or, it might be possible to use reflection to forcefully change the `System.lineSeparator` field. This is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: But `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");` is considered if I use write methods like `Files.write`.

Comment: well, it might be fetching the current system property; while `String.format` doesn't.

Comment: Is there no hope to make `String.format` fetch the current property?

Comment: try reflection, set System.lineSeparator="\n"

Comment: Hmm. I think Oracle needs to change its documentation. It really is misleading. Indeed, the source shows that `Files.write()` works directly with the property, whereas `Formatter.format()` works with `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic or, System.setProperty should trigger re-initialization of some fields in the System class itself.

Comment: @bayou.io `System.lineSeparator()` is *documented* such that it always returns the same value which is the *initial* value of the system property. As such, the way it works can't be changed because it will break existing code. The best that can be done is fit the documentation to the code.